# Gremlin query search by search key across multiple vertex properties

Tags: titan, gremlin

I am trying to write a search query where in the input is some search key and the requirement is to search among the vertices where the given input key matches the value of two or more property keys of the vertex. For example assuming that I have user vertices in my graph db with the following property keys:

- 1) User first name
- 2) User last name
- 3) User email

Now given a search key 'xyz' I have to search across the user vertices where any of the above three property keys matches the value 'xyz'. This is how I have approached the problem.

```
g.V.has('ENTITY_TYPE', 'USER').or(_().has('USER_EMAIL' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*') , _().has('USER_FNAME' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*''USER_EMAIL' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*') , _().has('USER_LNAME' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*')).dedup();
```

I have created the required mixed indices (three separate mixed indices) for USER_EMAIL, USER_FNAME and USER_LNAME as follows:

```
key = m.makePropertyKey("USER_EMAIL").dataType(String.class).make();
m.buildIndex("serachbyemail",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex("search");

key = m.makePropertyKey("USER_FNAME").dataType(String.class).make();
m.buildIndex("searchbyfname",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex("search");

key = m.makePropertyKey("USER_LNAME").dataType(String.class).make();
m.buildIndex("typemixed",Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex("search");
```

This works fine. But I want to know if this is the best approach to this kind of problem? Or is there a better way to do this? Also I am using gremlin java api to write the above query. I am using dedup() to remove the duplicate vertices.

Comment: Please add the index definition(s).

Comment: Updated the post with index definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 indices won't help to answer your query efficiently. Better create a single index that covers all of the 3 fields (that doesn't mean, that your query has to have a condition for all fields) and issue a direct index query:

**Sample graph:**

```
g = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties")
m = g.getManagementSystem()

user = m.makeVertexLabel("USER").make()
email = m.makePropertyKey("USER_EMAIL").dataType(String.class).make()
fname = m.makePropertyKey("USER_FNAME").dataType(String.class).make()
lname = m.makePropertyKey("USER_LNAME").dataType(String.class).make()

m.buildIndex("users", Vertex.class).addKey(email).addKey(fname).addKey(lname).indexOnly(user).buildMixedIndex("search")
m.commit()

ElementHelper.setProperties(g.addVertexWithLabel("USER"), "USER_EMAIL", "foo@bar.com", "USER_FNAME", "foo", "USER_LNAME", "bar")
ElementHelper.setProperties(g.addVertexWithLabel("USER"), "USER_EMAIL", "foo@xyz.com", "USER_FNAME", "foo", "USER_LNAME", "bar")
ElementHelper.setProperties(g.addVertexWithLabel("USER"), "USER_EMAIL", "abc@bar.com", "USER_FNAME", "foo", "USER_LNAME", "xyz")
ElementHelper.setProperties(g.addVertexWithLabel("USER"), "USER_EMAIL", "foo@baz.com", "USER_FNAME", "xyz", "USER_LNAME", "bar")
ElementHelper.setProperties(g.addVertexWithLabel("USER"), "USER_EMAIL", "xyz@bar.com", "USER_FNAME", "xyz", "USER_LNAME", "xyz")

g.commit()
```

**Direct index query:**

```
gremlin> g.indexQuery("users", 'v."USER_EMAIL":/.*xyz.*/ v."USER_FNAME":/.*xyz.*/ v."USER_LNAME":/.*xyz.*/').vertices()*.getElement()._().map()
==>{USER_FNAME=xyz, USER_LNAME=xyz, USER_EMAIL=xyz@bar.com}
==>{USER_FNAME=xyz, USER_LNAME=bar, USER_EMAIL=foo@baz.com}
==>{USER_FNAME=foo, USER_LNAME=xyz, USER_EMAIL=abc@bar.com}
==>{USER_FNAME=foo, USER_LNAME=bar, USER_EMAIL=foo@xyz.com}
```

As you can see I also replaced `ENTITY_TYPE` with a vertex label. The label can help to keep your index as small as possible. If, for example, another type of vertices (e.g. `PROFILE`) also uses the property `USER_EMAIL`, it wouldn't make it into the index (if it was created using `.indexOnly(user)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I tried this and the results are much better .Can this index work with gremlin query? If yes, will it be as efficient as the direct index query? Is there any way to add vertex label to the existing user vertices?  If there is some traversal required before reaching the user vertex (UNIVERSITY vertex -> DEPARTMENT vertices -> USER vertices) and then applying the search key, is there a way to achieve that in direct index query.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible using Gremlin. It would work with AND conditions, but OR'ing wouldn't use the index. Though I'm not sure if Titan 0.9 is already able to do that.
Vertex labels are immutable; you can only create a new vertex, copy the properties and edges from the old vertex and then drop the old vertex.
Like any global index query, direct index queries can not be used mid-traversal. In this case you would want to use a simple `.or()` step.

Comment: Thanks again! So does this implies that we cannot utilize mixed indices in the above scenario where in traversals are required?

Comment: Right. Of course you can use the filters (e.g. `.has('USER_EMAIL' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*')`) mid-traversal, but this would then be done in-memory. Global indices are only used for start steps.

Comment: Earlier you said that it would work with AND conditions. I thought you meant And pipe. I think what you really meant  was something like g.V.has('USER_EMAIL' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*'). Am I right?

Comment: Sorry if that was a bit confusing. By AND conditions I meant something like this: `g.V().has('USER_EMAIL' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*').has('USER_FNAME' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*').has('USER_LNAME' , TEXT.REGEX , '.*xyz.*')`, not the `and()` step.

Comment: Thanks.  I have used all these pipes a lot in my code (copySplit , or , filter). I didn't knew that these don't utilize indices. This is really helpful information.